# Building DOM with xerces and Java - how to prevent escaping of ampersand

Tags: xml-serialization, xerces

I am using xerces in Java to build a DOM.  For one of the fields that becomes a text node in the DOM, the data is being delivered from a source that has already turned any non ASCII and/or XML special characters into their entity names or numbers, e.g. "Banana&#174;"

I know the design of the system is wrong in terms the data source shouldn't be doing this but that is out of my control, but what I am wondering is if there is a way to somehow prevent this from being escaped and turned into "Banana&amp;#174;" without decoding first? (I know it will implicitly convert any chars it needs to so I could enter the raw char after decoding).

Example code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();      
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();      
    Document dom = db.newDocument();        
    Element root = dom.createElement("Companies");      
    dom.appendChild(root);      
    Element company = dom.createElement("Company");
    Text t = dom.createTextNode("Banana&#174;");        
    company.appendChild(t);     
    root.appendChild(company);      
    DOMImplementationRegistry dir = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance(); 
    DOMImplementationLS impl = 
        (DOMImplementationLS)dir.getDOMImplementation("LS");        
    LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
    LSOutput output = impl.createLSOutput();
    output.setByteStream(System.out);
    writer.write(dom, output);
```

Example Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Companies><Company>Banana&amp;#174;</Company></Companies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could somehow declare it in a CDATA section, it should be passed through as is.